# display list that in each row 1 li

Tags: html, css

How can I display the list that in each line I will have one li and not 2 li in one row?

```html
<div class="recent_questions promoted_questions pblock">
  <ul class="vertical_menu main_questions">
    <li>
      <span class="header">
                    <a href="covid.php">corona<img src="photos/Covid.gif"></a></span>
      <span class="questions"><span class="big_image">
                  <img class="photo_sub" src="photos/covid.jpg"/></span></span>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap your images into individual `<li>` elements, and they will appear below each other:

```html
<div class="recent_questions promoted_questions pblock">
    <ul class="vertical_menu main_questions">
        <li>
            <span class="header">
                <a href="covid.php">
                    corona
                    <img src="photos/Covid.gif">
                </a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="questions">
                <span class="big_image">
                    <img class="photo_sub" src="photos/covid.jpg" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's didn't work

Comment: it shows me 2 li's in every row, and I want it to be 1 li in a row

Comment: @Ofek I updated my answer and turned the code into a snippet, which you can execute and see the result (one image per line). You provided no CSS in your question, in case you are using CSS, that is modifying the layout, that could cause the problem. Please specify your issue and provide all resources. What do you mean by row, what should be in one row? Clarify that.

Comment: I have tried that on another page, it works, maybe CSS errors are causing the problem, thanks a lot David!